# Android ProgressBar stops being updated

Tags: multithreading, android-asynctask, android

I am trying to solve a problem with the UI of my application.

When entering in a specific `Activity`, the app looks for some files inside a directory and for each file requests some data to a REST API service.

The worker Thread is implemented as an `AsyncTask`:

`doInBackground` method recursively searches for files in a folder and its subfolders. 
If a file is found, a new request is submitted to a request-queue handled by Retrofit+OkHTTPClient.

Requests are asynchronous and the `Callback` function, once the information for a file are retrieved, calls a function that does some operations and then calls the `AsyncTask` `publishProgress()`.

`onProgressUpdate` is finally called to update current and max values of a `ProgressBar`.

The main issue I'm having is that after some time the `ProgressBar` stops being updated and I get the "Choreographer dropped frames" message, but `onProgressUpdate` is called every time and with updated values.

I think that the many HTTP requests are a bottleneck for frequent UI updates.

I also tried to create a `Thread` with priority set to `MAX_PRIORITY` to call `publishProgress` from it, no difference.

Which pattern should I follow to make the UI more responsive?

Here's some simplified code:

**AsyncTask**

```
public class MyAsyncTask implements myCustomListener{
    private int processed = 0;
    private int toProcess = 0;
    private MyCustomActivity mActivity;

    public MyAsyncTask(MyCustomActivity mActivity){
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        doScan(mRootDir);
        return null;
    }

    private void doScan(File rootDir){
        for(File file: rootDir.listFiles()){
            if(file.isDirectory()) doScan(file);
            else if(isWantedFile(file)) {
                MyQueues.addRequest(file,this);
                toProcess++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomEventListened(File f){
        //set f as processed
        processed++;
        publishProgress();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... voids) {
        if (processed > 1)
            mActivity.showProgressBar(); //If not visible, set visible
        mActivity.updateProgressBar(processed, toProcess);
        Log.i("Scan Progress", processed + "/" + toProcess); //this log print tells me that method is called properly
        if (processed == toProcess) {
            mActivity.hideProgressBar(); //If visible, set not visible
        }
    }

}
```

**RequestQueues**

```
public class MyQueues{
    private static LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> mRequestQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    private static ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4, Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, mRequestQueue);
    private static OkClient mOkClient;
    private static OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient;

    static{
        if(null==mOkHttpClient){
            File cache = MyApp.getCacheDir();
            HttpResponseCache resCache;
            try {
                resCache = new HttpResponseCache(cache, 10L * 1024 * 1024);
                mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                mOkHttpClient.setResponseCache(resCache);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if(null==mOkClient){
            mOkClient = new OkClient(mOkHttpClient);
        }
    }

    public static interface TheGamesDBService {
        @GET("/getData.php")
        void getData(@Query("id") String id, MyCallback<FileInfoClass> cb);
    }

    private static RestAdapter myAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setClient(mOkClient).setConverter(myConverter())
            .setExecutors(tpe, new MainThreadExecutor())
            .setEndpoint(Constants.MYENDPOINT).build();
    private static MyService mService = myAdapter
            .create(MyService.class);

    public static void addRequest(File f, MyCustomListener mListener) {
            MyCallback cb = new MyCallback(f, mListener);
            myService().getData(f.getName(),cb);
        }
    }

}
```

**MyCallback**

```
public class MyCallback implements Callback<FileInfoClass>{

    private File f;
    private MyCustomListener mListener;

    public MyCallback(File f, MyCustomListener mListener){
        this.f=f;
        this.mListener=mListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError response) {
        mListener.onCustomEventListened(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(FileInfoClass fic, Response response) {
        if(check(fic,f)){
            //store fic data...
        }
        mListener.onCustomEventListened(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the whole code as it's very long. I can post some portions of it if you tell me what part you want to see.

Comment: I would like to see code where you perform Retrofit calls, Retrofit callbacks, AsyncTask onProgressUpdate and wherever your ProgressBar is used.

Comment: @Loop sorry if it took this long, I added simplified code of what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to investigate it looking just at this code but I see potential problem.

Retrofit callback methods: `failure()` and `success()` are called on the main thread, eventually `publishProgress();` is called on the main thread. According to AsyncTask documentation this method should be called from `doInBackground()` method which is called on dedicated background thread. You should definitely consider refactoring code. To make it easier print to Logcat current thread name in different places: `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

Additionally, I have noticed that you keep strong reference to `Activity` inside `AsyncTask`. It's a very bad practice. To easily fix it, wrap `Activity` reference with `WeakReference` class.

If you decide to make bigger changes I would suggest to move background operations to dedicated `Service` with ThreadExecutor or use `IntentService` which provides queued background operations out of the box. Finally, to communicate progress changes to `Activity` use `BroadcastReceiver` along with `LocalBroadcastManager`.

**Update**

One more thing to add. If you are handling network operations in the background yourself there is no need to use Retrofit's Callback. It's good for request performed directly from UI. Instead, call retrofit requests synchronously.

Comment: Thank you for the precious hints! I edited my code following your directions: I removed the `Callback`s to perform the whole code in background and now the `ProgressBar` is properly updated. ~6000 requests and still no laggy UI!